# RowReduce does not work?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is my matrix that I want to reduce to reduce Echelon form. But it only gives me an identity matrix. Please help!

```
a1 = {0.9, -0.1, -0.2}; a2 = {-0.8, 0.9, -0.4}; a3 = {-0.1, -0.8, 0.4};
RowReduce[{a1, a2, a3}]

(* {{1, 0., 0.}, {0, 1, 0.}, {0, 0, 1}} *)
```

Comment: That is the correct reduction, so not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you want your `a`s to be the columns of the matrix, do `RowReduce[Transpose[{a1, a2, a3}]]`.

Comment: Can you show the answer you would like?

Comment: @Moo  Thank you guys, I just found out that I had a mistype, it is supposed to be 0.8 in a3. I was doubting something something was wrong with RowReduce in my Mathematica, but it was not.